# Import cells into the text of another cell preserving quotation marks

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Well, I did some research but I didn't find what I'm trying to do. I have this text:

"en":"B2",
"es":"C2",
"it":"D2",
"pt":"E2"

I have 4 columns with information in each cell. I need to "import" each cell information **inside** that, so I would get exactly this:

"en":"Hi", "es":"Hola", "it":"Ciao", "pt":"Olá"

Comment: Welcome. Thank you for sharing your efforts. Also check  [How to Ask](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [About asking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/asking). As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is this:

`="en:" & B2 & ", es:" & C2 & ", it:" & D2 & ", pt:" & E2`

#### EDIT

*(following your comment)*

**To preserve/include quotation marks(`"`), escape/prepend your `"`s with another `"`**.
In your case you should use:


```
="""en"":""" & B2 & """, ""es"":""" & C2 & """, ""it"":""" & D2 & """, ""pt"":""" & E2 &""""
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works, but it deletes the quotation marks, and I need them to be there. Is there a way to keep all quotation marks?

Comment: Do you need quotation marks in both the language as well as the words (`"en":"Hi"`) or just the words? (`en:"Hi"`). _I would personally suggest just the words_.

Comment: I need them both because the idea is to create a cell that I can just Copy+Paste.

Comment: Please check the updated formula. Remember to accept (and upvote).

Comment: It works, but when I Copy and Paste, it pastes the extra quote marks. :'( Is there a solution for this?

Comment: _...it is getting a bit confusing... :)_ How, where to and what do you "Copy-Paste"? Please share links for both your spreadsheet and where you paste it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98244/discussion-between-roberto-de-nobrega-and-marikamitsos).